# getline() no lee linea y sigue codigo c++

Tags: c++

tengo problemas para guardar string con espacios en una variable.

```
void generarTabla(paisesBolillero paises[32]) {

void titulo();
int menu();
titulo();
for(int i=0; i<32; i++) {
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre del pais N" << char(167) << ": " << i+1 << endl
    //cin >> paises[i].pais;
    getline(cin, paises[i].pais);       
    cout << "Ingrese el bolillero del pais N" << char(167) << ": " << i+1 << endl;
    cin >> paises[i].bolillero;
    cout << "Ingrese la confederacion del pais N" << char(167) << ": " << i+1 << endl;
    cin >> paises[i].confederacion;
    paises[i].libre = true;
    numPaises++;
}

if(numPaises == 31) {
    FILE * archivoPaises;
    archivoPaises = fopen ("paisesBolillero.dat", "wb");

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        fwrite (&paises[i], sizeof(struct paisesBolillero), 1, archivoPaises);      
    }
    fclose(archivoPaises);
}
```

}

Hice dos cosas:

```
cin >> paises[i].pais;
```

y falla cuando inserto un string con espacios, luego probe con esto:

```
getline(cin, paises[i].pais);
```

Pero cuando hago esto ultimo, no espera a que escriba algo y salta a la linea siguiente.

Que hago? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa cuando se ingresa un `cin` antes.
Para solucionarlo, debes colocar `cin.ignore();` antes de un `getline()` o luego de un `cin` y sepas que luego va un `getline` (la práctica y experiencia te hará saber donde es mejor colocarlo, ve probando distintos lugares).

```
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, paises[i].pais);
```

Comment: Mil gracias a la respuesta de Andy Samuel logre solucionar el problema con un cin.ignore();
Solo lo agregue una linea antes de la linea que tenia el problema. Nunca me había pasado eso, pero con eso lo solucione. gracias mil.

Answer (score 4):

Como bien sabes, cada vez que haces una lectura en C++, la misma bloquea la ejecución hasta que se presiona la tecla *enter*. Así, por ejemplo, en el siguiente código el resultado no aparecerá hasta que no se introduzcan los dos números y, posteriormente, se pulse la tecla *enter*:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::cout << a << b;
```

Y, además, el programa funcionará independientemente de que el separador utilizado sea un espacio (o veinte), o un salto de línea. ¿Cómo es posible?

`std::cin` posee ciertas características que permiten simplificar los mecanismos de lectura. Así, cuando tu escribes `std::cin >> a` y suponiendo en este caso que `a` es de tipo `int`, `std::cin` inspeccionará el *buffer* de entrada y descartará todos los espacios, tabuladores y saltos de línea que encuentre hasta dar con el primer caracter convertible a dígito numérico. De esta forma, al usar `std::cin`, te puedes despreocupar de los saltos de línea y otros separadores.

Sin embargo, `getline` no es tan inteligente y no descarta ningún caracter. Así, ante esta secuencia:

```
int a;
std::string linea;

std::cin >> a;
std::getline(std::cin,linea);
```

Nos encontramos con que la lectura de `std::cin` ha dejado un salto de línea en el *buffer* de entrada. Entonces `std::getline`, cuyo cometido es almacenar en una variable de tipo `std::string` todo lo que encuentre hasta el siguiente salto de línea, se encuentra con una cadena vacía.

El comportamiento de `std::getline` tiene su razón de ser, y es que esta función no es quien para decidir por ti cuándo debe ignorarse ese salto de línea y cuándo no. Esa es tu responsabilidad. Por otro lado, `std::cin` no es quien para decidir cuándo se debe eliminar el salto de línea (o el separador o separadores) que acompañen a la variable que se está leyendo.

Así pues, como te han comentado en otra respuesta, la solución pasa por descartar el salto de línea *antes* de llamar a `std::getline`:

```
std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::cin, paises[i].pais);
```

Estas líneas, si el usuario no hace cosas raras, funcionará bien, pero si al usuario le da por introducir espacios después del texto de *confederacion* , el programa volverá a fallar y el motivo es que con `ignore` únicamente estás descartando un caracter. Para eliminar todo lo que se encuentre entre la posición actual del *buffer* y el primer salto de línea (incluído), tienes que poner lo siguiente:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
std::getline(std::cin, paises[i].pais);
```

Donde `numeric_limits` es una plantilla que permite obtener información útil sobre los tipos nativos de C++. Así, el método `max()` devolverá el valor más alto que puedes almacenar en el tipo `int` (que es el tipo con el que hemos especializado la plantilla). Esta llamada de `ignore` descartará un máximo de `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` caracteres, salvo que se encuentre el caracter `\n` antes, en cuyo caso dicho caracter también será descartado y se detendrá el proceso de descarte.